# How to use loop when data type is dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

```
suspect = {'Height':6,'Colour':'Fair','Residency':'Pune'}
Name = input('Please enter your name')
Verification = int(input('Please enter Height ')

if Verification == suspect['Height']:
    print('Suspect is detected  for 1st level')
else:
    print('Suspect is not detected  for 1st level')**
```

Note that my scenario is: If `suspect` is detected with `{'Height': 3, 'Colour': 'Fair', 'resident': 'Pune'}`-condition the name should be saved and code should be continued running. It mean that `'Please enter your name'` and `'Please Enter Height'` should be continued to ask.

Comment: what if suspect is not detected? it should continue running your code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a while loop. At each loop, the program asks is you want continue.
In addition, a list allows to store the names of suspects

```
suspect = {'Height':6,'Colour':'Fair','Residency':'Pune'}


suspect_list = []
continu = "Y"
while(continu == "Y"):
    Name = input('Please enter your name: ')
    Verification = int(input('Please enter Height: '))
    if Verification == suspect['Height']:
        print('Suspect is detected  for 1st level')
        suspect_list.append(Name)
    else:
        print('Suspect is not detected  for 1st level')
    continu = str(input("Do you want continu (Y/N): "))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

Use `list(dict)` to get all key values.

## Code

```
//#colour --> color
suspect = {"Name":"Obama","Height":6,'Color':'Black','Residency':'Pune'}

//#List on a dict gives all key strings
suspect_depictions =(list(suspect))

floor = 1
run = True
while run:
    //#Enter info
    Name = input('Please enter your name: ')
    Height = int(input('Please enter Height: '))
    Color = input('Please enter your color: ')
    Residency = input('Please enter your residency: ')
    Still_a_suspect = True

    //#Check all depictions
    for depiction in suspect_depictions:
        if depiction == "Name":
            if suspect[depiction] == Name:
                print("Name match")
            else:
                print("Name dose not match")
                Still_a_suspect = False

        if depiction == "Height":
            if suspect[depiction] == Height:
                print("Height match")
            else:
                print("Height dose not match")
                Still_a_suspect = False

        if depiction == "Color":
            if suspect[depiction] == Color:
                print("Color match")
            else:
                print("Color dose not match")
                Still_a_suspect = False

        if depiction == "Residency":
            if suspect[depiction] == Residency:
                print("Residency match")
            else:
                print("Residency dose not match")
                Still_a_suspect = False

    if Still_a_suspect:
        run = False
        print("The suspect lives on the " +str(floor) + "th floor!")
    else:
        floor += 1
        print("")
        print("------------------------")
        print("")
```